# Realm database for public use?

Tags: ios, swift, database, realm

Can I use a Realm database for public? For example: In my app I can write a profile of myself and I can publish this profile.So I want to write an user profile (name, e-mail, age, etc.) into my database. So far so good. I know that I can save data for local using, but is it possible for EVERY USER in the world (not only your local device) to access to this data(Like with Facebook, Twitter, Instagram, etc.) on a certain way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The is no such feature in Realm currently. It is tracked on this issue https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/913.

In the meanwhile, you should use other cloud services to share Realm data files.